# How can I control the sequence of the code execution in protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

When I am running the below code, I observed that the last 3 lines with *'var robot'* are executed at the beginning itself and not after clicking on the textArea. How can I control the sequence of code execution?

```
var robot = require("robotjs");
it('Testing robotjs', function () {
    browser.driver.get(www.abc.com");
    element(by.xpath(button1)).click();
    element(by.xpath(textArea)).click();

    robot.typeString("hello world");
    robot.moveMouse("605", "429");
    robot.mouseClick("left");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the Protractor's [Control Flow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md) in action, put the last 3 lines into the last click's promise resolution function:

```
var robot = require("robotjs");
it('Testing robotjs', function () {
    browser.driver.get("www.abc.com");
    element(by.xpath(button1)).click();
    element(by.xpath(textArea)).click().then(function () {
        robot.typeString("hello world");
        robot.moveMouse("605", "429");
        robot.mouseClick("left");
    });
});
```